Position in hierarchy as ordinal predictor in linear regression
I'm writing my thesis and I'm unsure about the analysis procedure. One of the hypotheses is: "A higher position of the deceased in the attachment hierarchy of the bereaved predicts a higher level of complicated grief." The position in the attachment hierarchy is a variable created as a median composite score of three items, where 0 means the deceased was not in the attachment hierarchy of the bereaved (attachment hierarchy is a psychological concept), 1 = ranked 4th, 2 = ranked 3rd, 3 = ranked 2nd, and 4 = ranked 1st in the hierarchy. I want to use multiple linear regression (I have other predictors as well) to determine if a higher rank predicts a higher level of complicated grief. Complicated grief level is a continuous variable. Therefore, the "Position in the hierarchy" variable takes only values from 0 to 4. Dummy coding doesn't make sense to me because it's not a nominal variable but ordinal. When I try to generate some descriptive statistics or scatterplots for the Position in hierarchy variable, the graphs look weird compared to other continuous independent variables. Am I making something wrong? Thank you.

Hi Sabina, can you provide additional details to ensure people can answer you adequately please ?

Hi, which details do you mean?

Regarding this: "When I try to generate some descriptive statistics or scatterplots for the Position in hierarchy variable, the graphs look weird compared to other continuous independent variables"
